# Run program with environment set to variables in a file

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I would like to run a program (in this case Python) with only the environment variables defined in a file, say `vars.env`:

```
FOO=bar
X=12
```

Here's a simply Python script that prints the environment:

```
import os
print os.environ
```

If I run `env -i python script.py`, os.environ is empty as expected. Likewise, if I run

```
$ env -i FOO=bar X=12 python env.py
```

I get

```
env: {'X': '12', 'FOO': 'bar'}
```

However what I would like to do is load the environment from my `vars.env` file when running the script. How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: One thing that I could do is cat this env file, like `` env -i `cat vars.env` python env.py `` but I would prefer to be able to source it in some way.

Comment: I don't understand the question: you seem to already have found a way to “run program with environment set to variables in a file”. Is the question how to do that from inside the Python script, so that you can directly run `/path/to/myscript.py`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the file you show, you should be able to do:

```
(set -f ; IFS='
' ; env - $(cat /path/to/file) /path/to/your/program
)
```

If it doesn't work then it is only because you need to format your environment file first. Here's an example:

```
(set -f ; IFS='
' ; env - $(cat) printenv 
) <<\ENV
variable1=value1
variable2=value2
variable3=value3 an$d s'om\e m"ore
ENV
###OUTPUT###
variable1=value1
variable2=value2
variable3=value3 an$d s'om\e m"ore
```

I at first thought you could do it through the shell - but it will probably set some of its own environment before calling your program. But I can at least demonstrate that the arguments are assigned correctly:

```
(set -f; IFS='
' ; env - $(cat) sh -c 'echo "$variable3"'
) <<\ENV
variable1=value1
variable2=value2
variable3=value3 an$d s'om\e m"ore
ENV
###OUTPUT###
value3 an$d s'om\e m"ore
```

Still, if you would prefer to source it, here's how you can using the shell:

```
(echo '$1'; cat; echo '$2') <<\ENV |\
env - sh -s -- 'set -a' printenv
variable1=value1
variable2=value2
variable3='value3 an$d s'\''om\e m"ore'
ENV
###OUTPUT###
PWD=/home/mikeserv/test
SHLVL=1
variable1=value1
variable2=value2
variable3=value3 an$d s'om\e m"ore
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Notice that I removed the `$IFS` stuff - that's not necessary this way - but I did have to get specific about the quotes in the file. Here I'm essentially `.dot` sourcing `stdin` - reading the `|pipe` as input - but you can use any file. I use `set -a` before reading the input file to set the `--allexport` option.

That is a result of using `bash`'s `sh` - it adds `$PWD`, `$SHLVL` and `$_`. With `dash` it is a little better. And `dash` doesn't add a bunch of exports either, so you can specify the `-a` parameter on the command line:

```
(cat; echo '$1') <<\ENV |\
env - dash -sa -- printenv 
variable1=value1
variable2=value2
variable3='value3 an$d s'\''om\e m"ore'
ENV
variable1=value1
variable2=value2
variable3=value3 an$d s'om\e m"ore
PWD=/home/mikeserv/test
```

Only `$PWD` comes through.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in `Python`:

```
$ cat config.py
env = {
    'FOO' : 'bar',
    'X'   : '12',
}

$ cat test.py
import os
import config

os.environ.clear()
os.environ.update(config.env)
print os.environ
```

Then:

```
$ python test.py
{'X': '12', 'FOO': 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to read the file into an array, and then use the array as an argument. The advantage compared to using process substitution is that it can handle values with whitespace in them. Example:

```
$ cat file
FOO=bar
X=12
var=a b c

$ IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra vars < file
$ env -i "${vars[@]}" python env.py
{'var': 'a b c', 'X': '12', 'FOO': 'bar'}
```