# set environment variables from stdout

Tags: shell, pipe, environment-variables

How can you do the equivalent of piping stdout to 'export'?

For background, I have a non-shell script that generates environment variables like so:

```
DATABASE_URL='someurl'
MAIL_KEY='key'
REDIS_URL='redis connection string'
```

I would like to take that output and execute it, something like:
`generate-env | xargs export`

Unfortunately, export isn't a binary, and neither is eval. I would prefer not to have to write my output to a file and run it with source. Is this even possible?

Comment: really similar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146168/run-program-with-environment-set-to-variables-in-a-file?rq=1 ; maybe something along the lines of `env $(generate-env) $SHELL` ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `eval`:

```
$ set -a
$ eval "$(command_that_generate_output)"
$ set +a
$ sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$DATABASE_URL"'
someurl
```

Comment: He has a "non-shell script" generating the data. Could be a C program or anything.

Comment: Doesn't matter. `command_that_generate_output` generates output that looks like shell commands. eval takes that output and actually *treats* it like shell commands. The `-a` option causes all those variables to be exported. Very elegant.

Comment: Ahh, looking at the edit history, I see you were commenting on the first version of the answer, which was actually significantly different.